# Using an array to store data from sql query, but is repeating the result

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a query which as only one row has a result and I am trying to store its content inside an array. The problem is that the code is putting inside the array $vs31 five times the real result and I don't understand why.

```
$query1 = "SELECT PROCESSO,DATAMSG, CATEGORIA_DESC, VALOR, CRITICO FROM TABLEX";
$result1 = oci_parse($connect, $query1);
oci_execute($result1);

$c1=array();
oci_fetch_all($result1, $c1, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

$f=0;

foreach ($c1 as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

        $vs3=array();
        $f++; 
        $vs3['id']= $f;
        $vs3['title']='VSC - '.$row['CATEGORIA_DESC'];
        $vs3['startdate']=$row['DATAMSG'];
        $vs3['enddate']=$row['DATAMSG'];
        $vs3['description']= 'VALOR - '.$row['VALOR'];
        $vs3['date_display']='ho';
        $vs3['icon']='plus_blue.png';
        $vs3['importance']='30';
        $vs3['css_class']='hot-event';

        array_push($vs31,$vs3);
    }
}

print_r($vs31);
```

What I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103
            [title] => VSC - ECG_HR                        
            [startdate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [enddate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [description] => VALOR - 59
            [date_display] => ho
            [icon] => plus_blue.png
            [importance] => 30
            [css_class] => hot-event
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 104
            [title] => VSC - ECG_HR                        
            [startdate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [enddate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [description] => VALOR - 59
            [date_display] => ho
            [icon] => plus_blue.png
            [importance] => 30
            [css_class] => hot-event
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 105
            [title] => VSC - ECG_HR                        
            [startdate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [enddate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [description] => VALOR - 59
            [date_display] => ho
            [icon] => plus_blue.png
            [importance] => 30
            [css_class] => hot-event
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 106
            [title] => VSC - ECG_HR                        
            [startdate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [enddate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [description] => VALOR - 59
            [date_display] => ho
            [icon] => plus_blue.png
            [importance] => 30
            [css_class] => hot-event
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 107
            [title] => VSC - ECG_HR                        
            [startdate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [enddate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [description] => VALOR - 59
            [date_display] => ho
            [icon] => plus_blue.png
            [importance] => 30
            [css_class] => hot-event
        )
)
```

What it want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103
            [title] => VSC - ECG_HR                        
            [startdate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [enddate] => 2015-04-27 23
            [description] => VALOR - 59
            [date_display] => ho
            [icon] => plus_blue.png
            [importance] => 30
            [css_class] => hot-event
        )
)
```

Comment: Your query is returning 5 results and you're looping over them and pushing them into `$vs31` array. That's because your table has 5 entries and you're not using a WHERE clause to filter them. If you want a different output, try changing your query or use LIMIT 1.

Comment: Not true the table has only 1 entry not 5 so I don't need a WHERE clause for anything.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I was looking only to `id` field. If you do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($c1);` before the `for` statement, what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking only one value and pushing it multiple times and
You are not using $value any where in the loop.
Try this.

```
foreach ($c1 as $row) {


        $vs3=array();
        $f++; 
        $vs3['id']= $f;
        $vs3['title']='VSC - '.$row['CATEGORIA_DESC'];
        $vs3['startdate']=$row['DATAMSG'];
        $vs3['enddate']=$row['DATAMSG'];
        $vs3['description']= 'VALOR - '.$row['VALOR'];
        $vs3['date_display']='ho';
        $vs3['icon']='plus_blue.png';
        $vs3['importance']='30';
        $vs3['css_class']='hot-event';

        array_push($vs31,$vs3);

}
```

Let me know if that works fine..